# Change WiFi Mac Address

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, mac-address

I am running on rooted Moto E (XT1022) Android 4.4, and want to change WiFi MAC Address. I had tried installing BusyBox with Terminal and run the following command.

```
busybox ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

This is Temporally, In fact it doesn't actually changes the MAC Address, If I look under Settings => About Phone => Status => WiFi MAC address is still old one.

I had found a file under, which I guess to do something with MAC Address `/etc/firmware/wlan/prima/WCNSS_qcom_cfg.ini` which is exact same in this link [WCNSS_qcom_cfg.ini](https://git.i4g.me/Abhinav/android_device_sony_tianchi/blob/a41e2c7659265bb65f37123276e38b5f020e21a1/rootdir/system/etc/firmware/wlan/prima/WCNSS_qcom_cfg.ini)

Note: none of the MAC changer app working on Play Store - Might for this device.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Can you tell the output of `find /sys/devices -name "*wlan*"` after `su`